# Write an Arel inner join query without `find_by_sql`

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, arel

In a Rails 5 project, I have a query method for an association that currently uses an SQL string, and I'm trying to refactor it to use only Arel. I'm wondering if it's possible to write this whole query method without using `to_sql` and `find_by_sql`.

The query is an INNER_JOIN with a join table.

Here's the old, SQL string method:

```rb
class User < AbstractModel
  ...

  # Return an Array of Projects that this User is an admin for.
  def projects_admin
    @projects_admin ||= Project.find_by_sql(%(
      SELECT projects.* FROM projects, user_groups_users
      WHERE projects.admin_group_id = user_groups_users.user_group_id
        AND user_groups_users.user_id = #{id}
    ))
  end
```

Here's my Arel rewrite, which gets the same query results:

```rb
  # Return an Array of Projects that this User is an admin for.
  def projects_admin
    projects = Project.arel_table
    # for join tables with no model, need to create an Arel::Table object
    # so we can use Arel methods on it, eg access columns
    u_g_users = Arel::Table.new("user_groups_users")

    arel = projects.project(Arel.star).join(u_g_users).
           on(projects[:admin_group_id].eq(u_g_users[:user_group_id]).
                 and(u_g_users[:user_id].eq(id)))

    # is there a way to write this without going to_sql and back?
    Project.find_by_sql(arel.to_sql)
  end
```

What i'm trying to do is change the last line of my new `projects_admin` method so that it calls the relation directly, without using `find_by_sql` on `arel.to_sql`.

If i just return the `arel`, it's not an array of `Project`s as I would expect.

But maybe this is a nonsensical desire, and it has to be phrased this way. Many examples suggest this is the case.

I've tried every example I could find, but I think the root of the problem is my misunderstanding of how a join interacts with the class of object i'm generating, an `Arel::SelectManager`.

Here are the model associations in question. "user_groups_users" is a join table between "user_groups" and "users" - there are ony the "User", "UserGroup" and "Project" models here.

```rb
class User < AbstractModel
  has_many :projects_created, class_name: "Project"
  has_and_belongs_to_many :user_groups,
                          class_name: "UserGroup",
                          join_table: "user_groups_users"
```

```rb
class UserGroup < AbstractModel
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_one :project
  has_one :admin_project, class_name: "Project", foreign_key: "admin_group_id"
```

```rb
class Project < AbstractModel
  belongs_to :admin_group, class_name: "UserGroup",
                           foreign_key: "admin_group_id"
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :user_group
```

Comment: You should be able to change the last line to `Project.joins(*arel.join_sources)`. Other options include: `Project.from(arel.as(Project.table_name))` this will create a sub query.

Comment: Correction the latter suggestion would require you to change `Arel.star` to `projects[Arel.star]` as you would need the table qualification to limit it to just the columns in the projects table

Comment: Ah - thanks. This is what I ended up using, because the ActiveRecord `joins` in max's answer below initiated two extra joins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I belive that you're overlooking a much simpler solution which is to add an indirect assocation and do a LEFT JOIN:

```ruby
class Project < AbstractModel
  belongs_to :admin_group, class_name: "UserGroup",
                           foreign_key: "admin_group_id"
  has_many :admin_group_users, 
    through: :admin_group,
    source: :users # the name of the assocation on UserGroup
  # ...
end
```

```ruby
Project.joins(:admin_group_users)
       .where(users: { id: id })
```

Comment: Thanks Max, that's incredibly elegant.

Comment: `foreign_key` is unnecessary as it is implied by the association name. Also I don't see a LEFT JOIN?

Comment: @engineersmnky you are right, the above answer does not create a left join, it creates several inner joins. The original SQL also was an inner join.

Comment: @max I'm not sure I even need the new association: how about `Project.joins(admin_group: :users).where(users: { id: id })`?

Comment: @max - One problem with the elegant ActiveRecord version, the SQL Rails generates through those associations is not elegant at all: `SELECT projects.* FROM projects INNER JOIN user_groups ON user_groups.id = projects.admin_group_id INNER JOIN user_groups_users ON user_groups_users.user_group_id = user_groups.id INNER JOIN users ON users.id = user_groups_users.user_id WHERE users.id = 1`

Comment: You don't need the assocation but its usually good to encapsulate the logic in the model.